# How to calculate skimage-like histogram of image using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, histogram, scikit-image

In a previously-created code, histogram was calculated using the `skimage` module, in the following way:

```
h = skimage.exposure.histogram(img, nbins=256)
```

But, now, for some reasons, I cannot use `skimage` but only OpenCV.
So, when I tried

```
h = cv2.calcHist(img, [0], None, [256], [0,256])
```

the output of `h` of `skimage` and `h` of OpenCV are different and the code after this breaks.

So, what am I supposed to do to make the OpenCV's histogram output the same as before?

Example image:

[image]

(Please click on the image to view it clearly. It is just a green colour with noise added.)

Then I convert it to `black-and-white` using:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
img = img/255              #to convert values from [0, 255] to [0, 1]
img = img[:, :, 0]
```

Histogram of `skimage`:

```
(array([  4,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         3,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
        15,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,  23,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,  49,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,  94,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0, 152,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0, 183,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0, 207,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0, 200,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0, 187,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 165,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 141,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  78,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  58,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  39,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   8,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   4,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1], dtype=int64), array([0.08249847, 0.08278952, 0.08308058, 0.08337163, 0.08366268,
       0.08395374, 0.08424479, 0.08453585, 0.0848269 , 0.08511795,
       0.08540901, 0.08570006, 0.08599112, 0.08628217, 0.08657322,
       0.08686428, 0.08715533, 0.08744638, 0.08773744, 0.08802849,
       0.08831955, 0.0886106 , 0.08890165, 0.08919271, 0.08948376,
       0.08977482, 0.09006587, 0.09035692, 0.09064798, 0.09093903,
       0.09123009, 0.09152114, 0.09181219, 0.09210325, 0.0923943 ,
       0.09268536, 0.09297641, 0.09326746, 0.09355852, 0.09384957,
       0.09414063, 0.09443168, 0.09472273, 0.09501379, 0.09530484,
       0.09559589, 0.09588695, 0.096178  , 0.09646906, 0.09676011,
       0.09705116, 0.09734222, 0.09763327, 0.09792433, 0.09821538,
       0.09850643, 0.09879749, 0.09908854, 0.0993796 , 0.09967065,
       0.0999617 , 0.10025276, 0.10054381, 0.10083487, 0.10112592,
       0.10141697, 0.10170803, 0.10199908, 0.10229013, 0.10258119,
       0.10287224, 0.1031633 , 0.10345435, 0.1037454 , 0.10403646,
       0.10432751, 0.10461857, 0.10490962, 0.10520067, 0.10549173,
       0.10578278, 0.10607384, 0.10636489, 0.10665594, 0.106947  ,
       0.10723805, 0.10752911, 0.10782016, 0.10811121, 0.10840227,
       0.10869332, 0.10898437, 0.10927543, 0.10956648, 0.10985754,
       0.11014859, 0.11043964, 0.1107307 , 0.11102175, 0.11131281,
       0.11160386, 0.11189491, 0.11218597, 0.11247702, 0.11276808,
       0.11305913, 0.11335018, 0.11364124, 0.11393229, 0.11422335,
       0.1145144 , 0.11480545, 0.11509651, 0.11538756, 0.11567862,
       0.11596967, 0.11626072, 0.11655178, 0.11684283, 0.11713388,
       0.11742494, 0.11771599, 0.11800705, 0.1182981 , 0.11858915,
       0.11888021, 0.11917126, 0.11946232, 0.11975337, 0.12004442,
       0.12033548, 0.12062653, 0.12091759, 0.12120864, 0.12149969,
       0.12179075, 0.1220818 , 0.12237286, 0.12266391, 0.12295496,
       0.12324602, 0.12353707, 0.12382812, 0.12411918, 0.12441023,
       0.12470129, 0.12499234, 0.12528339, 0.12557445, 0.1258655 ,
       0.12615656, 0.12644761, 0.12673866, 0.12702972, 0.12732077,
       0.12761183, 0.12790288, 0.12819393, 0.12848499, 0.12877604,
       0.1290671 , 0.12935815, 0.1296492 , 0.12994026, 0.13023131,
       0.13052237, 0.13081342, 0.13110447, 0.13139553, 0.13168658,
       0.13197763, 0.13226869, 0.13255974, 0.1328508 , 0.13314185,
       0.1334329 , 0.13372396, 0.13401501, 0.13430607, 0.13459712,
       0.13488817, 0.13517923, 0.13547028, 0.13576134, 0.13605239,
       0.13634344, 0.1366345 , 0.13692555, 0.13721661, 0.13750766,
       0.13779871, 0.13808977, 0.13838082, 0.13867188, 0.13896293,
       0.13925398, 0.13954504, 0.13983609, 0.14012714, 0.1404182 ,
       0.14070925, 0.14100031, 0.14129136, 0.14158241, 0.14187347,
       0.14216452, 0.14245558, 0.14274663, 0.14303768, 0.14332874,
       0.14361979, 0.14391085, 0.1442019 , 0.14449295, 0.14478401,
       0.14507506, 0.14536612, 0.14565717, 0.14594822, 0.14623928,
       0.14653033, 0.14682138, 0.14711244, 0.14740349, 0.14769455,
       0.1479856 , 0.14827665, 0.14856771, 0.14885876, 0.14914982,
       0.14944087, 0.14973192, 0.15002298, 0.15031403, 0.15060509,
       0.15089614, 0.15118719, 0.15147825, 0.1517693 , 0.15206036,
       0.15235141, 0.15264246, 0.15293352, 0.15322457, 0.15351562,
       0.15380668, 0.15409773, 0.15438879, 0.15467984, 0.15497089,
       0.15526195, 0.155553  , 0.15584406, 0.15613511, 0.15642616,
       0.15671722]))
```

Histogram of `OpenCV`:

```
array([[ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 1.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 2.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 7.],
   [ 8.],
   [13.],
   [12.],
   [20.],
   [20.],
   [17.],
   [ 5.],
   [ 8.],
   [ 4.],
   [10.],
   [ 3.],
   [20.],
   [ 2.],
   [18.],
   [11.],
   [39.],
   [12.],
   [44.],
   [13.],
   [23.],
   [ 8.],
   [26.],
   [ 8.],
   [12.],
   [ 1.],
   [ 2.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 2.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 1.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.],
   [ 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Post the input image.

Comment: Skimage histogram returns the centers of bins and does not rebin integer arrays. The first set are the counts and the second set are the normalized counts, i.e, bin counts divided by the total counts. So skimage histogram bins may be on different boundaries than OpenCV. Skimage also returns the histogram of the flattened array. So all 3 channels will be included if not grayscale image unless you separate channels and process each separately. What kind of image are you using? Color or grayscale?

Comment: @fmw42, the input image actually changes during the operation. For the example above, I have edited the question.

Comment: @fmw42, I am using black-and-white image for calculating the histogram.

Comment: I assume you mean grayscale not just black and white. But still the bins are centered differently, I assume, from the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I mean greyscale image, with just a single channel.

Comment: So, what should be done to avoid different-centered bins?

Comment: I do not know. I do not think you can modify skimage. You might be able to modify opencv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `skimage.exposure.histogram(img, nbins=256)` returns a tuple with two arrays, the first one being the total number of pixels of that specific value in the given `img`, and the second array is normalized to `1`.
So, if you just want to find the total number of pixels of a given value, then you can use this :

```
def histogram(img):
    img = (img*255).astype(int)
    a = [0 for x in range(256)]
    for x in range(256):
        a[x] = np.count_nonzero(img == x)
    return a
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of stuff going wrong here, I'm afraid. To reconstruct your results, I used this piece of code:

```py
import cv2
import skimage.exposure

# Read image as-is
img = cv2.imread('TjFAo.png')

# Histogram OpenCV - incorrect usage
h_ocv = cv2.calcHist(img, [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
print(h_ocv.T)
# [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  2.  0.  7.  8. 13. 12. 20. 20.
#   17.  5.  8.  4. 10.  3. 20.  2. 18. 11. 39. 12. 44. 13. 23.  8. 26.  8.
# ...

# Some image manipulation - why? whatfor?
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
img = img / 255
img = img[:, :, 0]

# Histogram skimage
h_ski = skimage.exposure.histogram(img, nbins=256)
print(h_ski[0])
# [  4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0
#    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  15   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# ...
```

- You calculate the OpenCV histogram on the blue channel of the original image. Or, to be precise, you actually don't do that, because the usage is incorrect here. You need to put `img` in brackets, too.
- You convert the image to the [YUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) color space, and then take the first channel for the `skimage` histogram. Why? What do you have in mind here?
- You don't need to enforce values in the range of `[0.0 ... 1.0]` for `skimage` here.

Let's have a look at the correct usages, first let's check the blue channel of the original image:

```py
import cv2
import skimage.exposure

# Read image as-is
img = cv2.imread('TjFAo.png')

# Histogram OpenCV - brackets around the image!
h_ocv = cv2.calcHist([img], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
print(h_ocv.T)
# [[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   2.   9.  10.  27.  62.
#   107. 154. 174. 208. 213. 193. 166. 134.  73.  52.  20.   4.   1.   1.
# ...

# Histogram skimage - set source_range!
h_ski = skimage.exposure.histogram(img[..., 0], nbins=256, source_range='dtype')
print(h_ski[0])
# [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   9  10  27  62 107 154 174 208
#  213 193 166 134  73  52  20   4   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# ...
```

If you actually want to have the histograms of the grayscaled image, convert the image in the first place:

```py
import cv2
import skimage.exposure

# Read image as-is
img = cv2.imread('TjFAo.png')

# Convert to grayscale
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Histogram OpenCV - brackets around the image!
h_ocv = cv2.calcHist([img], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
print(h_ocv.T)
# [[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
#     0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   4.   3.  15.  23.  49.  94. 152.
# ...

# Histogram skimage - set source_range!
h_ski = skimage.exposure.histogram(img, nbins=256, source_range='dtype')
print(h_ski[0])
# [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#    0   0   0   4   3  15  23  49  94 152 183 207 200 187 165 141  78  58
# ...
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
OpenCV:        4.5.1
scikit-image:  0.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! But, still, the values `h_ocv` and `h_ski[0]` are not the same....why is that so? Also, setting `source_range="dtype"` breaks the previous code. The previously written code uses the actual number of pixels of that specific value, not in the capped range of `(0, 256)`

Comment: Why are they not the same? I get `True` for `print(np.all(h_ocv.flatten().astype(np.uint8) == h_ski[0]))`!? If you have (compatibility) issues within your code, you should post that code, too. You can leave out `source_range`. I added that only for comparison reasons.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to assert that I cannot do `source_range="dtype"` in while calculating `h_ski`